# Receiving the Progress as a File Uploads

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have some code that uploads a file and I am looking for a way to receive back the progress percentage so I can feed that into a progress bar. I tried ProgressEventInit and ProgressEvent but I have had no luck getting what I need. Anyone have any ideas. Below is the code:

```
function objToQuery(obj: {[key: string]: any}) {
  if (R.isEmpty(obj)) {
    return '';
  }
  return `?${R.toPairs(obj).map(kvPair => kvPair.join('=')).join('&')}`;
}

export default async function request<T>(url: string, options: RequestInit) {
  const response = await window.fetch(url, { credentials: 'include', ...options });
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
  const json = (await parseJSON<T>(response))!;
  return checkStatus(response, json);
}

export async function postFiles<T>(url: string, postForm: FormData, queryData: {} = {}) {
  const headers: HeadersInit = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  };

  return request<T>(`${apiRoot}/${url}${objToQuery(queryData)}`, {
    headers,
    method: 'POST',
    body: postForm,
  });
}
```

Comment: you're using fetch. this isn't supported with the fetch api yet. you could refactor your code to use xhr, as in the answer below though.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [file_upload_demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM69GVNGDTP7)

Note: This may not work in snippet due to cross origin policy, try it on your machine.

Hope this would help.

```js
function postFile() {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file1', $('#file1')[0].files[0]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        var file1Size = $('#file1')[0].files[0].size;

        if (e.loaded <= file1Size) {
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / file1Size * 100);
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
        } 

        if(e.loaded == e.total){
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(100 + '%').html(100 + '%');
        }
    });   

    request.open('post', '/echo/html/');
    request.timeout = 45000;
    request.send(formdata);
}
```

```css
.progress-wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.progress-wrapper .progress {
    background-color:green;
    width:0%;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form1">
    <input id="file1" type="file" />
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-file1" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postFile()">Upload File</button>
</form>
</html>
```

[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is pretty good solution for react

```
    upload(files) {
      const config = {
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
          var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
          console.log(percentCompleted)
        }
      }
    
      let data = new FormData()
      data.append('file', files[0])
    
      axios.put('/endpoint/url', data, config)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: jquery has nothing to do with ajax, other than it happens to have method with that name. there is really no good reason for jquery to have been included in this example.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to convert an Axiosresponse to a fetch Response?

Comment: @shellac2020 I'm not sure whats big difference between fetch response and axios response,

getting response in fetch
`let data = await response.json()`

getting response in axios
`let data = await response.data` , hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a small open source library [modern-multi-part](https://github.com/geo-systems/modern-multi-part) which wraps `XMLHttpRequest` in an easier to use, promise-based endpoint.

You can track progress and cancel an ongoing request. Here is sample code:

```js
// If you're using npm:
import { sendMultiPart } from "modern-multi-part";
// If you imported via script in HTML
const sendMultiPart = ModernMultiPart.sendMultiPart;

// Sample file - you would usually get that from a file input field
const file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", { type: "text/plain" });

// Returns a normal promise you can await.
// Monitor progress with the "onprogress" callback
const resultPromise = sendMultiPart(
  "https://httpbin.org/post",
  { file, textField: "sample-text" },
  {
    onprogress: (pe: ProgressEvent) =>
      console.log(100 * Math.floor((pe.loaded / pe.total), "%"),
  }
);

// The promise has additional "cancel" method
// Typically, this is used from a cancel button onClick callback
resultPromise.cancel() // <-- will cancel operation

resultPromise.then(result => {
  // Prints server response - e.g. 200
  console.log(result.httpStatus);
  // Prints response text (e.g. JSON response)
  console.log(result.responseText);
  // Prints whether the operation was aborted/cancelled using the "cancel" method
  console.log(result.aborted);
})
```

And here's a [Sandbox demo with React](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lumiere-uys3jn?file=/src/App.tsx).